# JTable sorting and rendering

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and I sort it according to a specific column. Then I colored a table cell according to a specific condition.. the problem is that when the table gets sorted the position of colored cell is still in the same location.

### Code

````
secondary_table=new JTable(table_model); 
TableRowSorter<TableModel>  sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(secondary_table.getModel());
secondary_table.setRowSorter(sorter);
ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
int columnIndexToSort = 3;
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
sorter.sort();
secondary_table=new JTable(table_model){
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);      
            if (value.equals("غائب")) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.red);
                 comp.setForeground(Color.white);
            } else if (value.equals("دوام كامل")) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.green);
                comp.setForeground(Color.black);
            } else if (value.equals("دوام جزئي دخول فقط") || value.equals("دوام جزئي خروج فقط") ) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                comp.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
         else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            comp.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
JScrollPane scrollPane1= new JScrollPane();
JFrame frame1=new JFrame(employee_name);
JPanel pp=new JPanel();
frame1.add(pp);
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
frame1.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(scrollPane1.add(secondary_table)), "Center");
frame1.pack();```
````

Comment: For better help sooner: 1) Choose tags carefully (this was missing two important tags). 2) ([Edit] to) add a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Once a table is sorted, we need to rely on methods like [`convertRowIndexToView(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView(int)) & [`convertRowIndexToModel(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)).

This is covered in the official tutorial at [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).